# same code works in java but doesn't work in android

Tags: java, android

```
try {
     //link below might contain offensive advertisemensts
     url = new URL("http://wasabisyrup.com/archives/GWB5lyn4FM8");
     urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     int c = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
.
.
.
```

this block of code gives response code 200 when compiled on a java ide, but it throws 403 error when ran on android with asynctask. This is driving me crazy. Please help

android code example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
            new DownloadFilesTask().execute();
        }
    });


}

private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://wasabisyrup.com/archives/GWB5lyn4FM8");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int c = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(c);
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        //setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {

    }
}
```

the output im getting :

> I/System.out: 403
>   W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://wasabisyrup.com/archives/GWB5lyn4FM8
>                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)
>   W/System.err:     at ml.melun.junhea.web_test.MainActivity$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:47)
>                     at ml.melun.junhea.web_test.MainActivity$DownloadFilesTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:35)
>                     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
>                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Comment: You should put the android code that does not work and more info about the endpoint you are hitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a proxy and check what you send in each case. You might find some extra headers can cause issues depending on how the backend handles them.